# Limiting row returns in table column search

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to look up some data from a table in Excel, using the following formula

```
=IF(Table_People[Polity]=lookup_PolityRuler, Table_People[Name],"")
```

This does return only the rows that I want as a dynamic range. However, it also returns blank rows where the other data was (see below):

[image: Blank Rows in Lookup]

How can I (/ is it possible to) get just the rows from the data using a formula such as this?

Comment: Have you looked at the Unique formula? https://www.get-digital-help.com/how-to-automatically-create-a-unique-list-and-remove-blanks/

Comment: Wouldn't FILTER be a better option then IF? `=FILTER(Table_People[Name],Table_People[Polity]=lookup_PolityRuler)`

Comment: @P.b It was indeed. Managed to get there in the end myself. Didn't realise that dynamic arrays were a thing until today. Was a good discovery!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have Excel as part of the Office 365 product, you can simply 'wrap' a filter around the desired formulation you have specified in this Q, *viz* (screenshot/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98F2CAUVQ6vZHURVT?e=dBcHpR) refer):

```
=LET(form,IF(Table6[Polity]=$B$4,Table6[Name],""),FILTER(form,form<>""))
```

[image: Screenshot]

*(of course, applying the filter directly with the criteria `Table6[Polity]=$B$4` would be a simpler / quicker soln..) i.e.*

```
=FILTER(Table6[Name],Table6[Polity]=$B$4)
```

[image]